# Phonegap Sound doesn't play in app

Tags: html, cordova, audio

i recently downloaded a HTML5 project from GitHub. The project is a flappy bird copy. I 
The link to GitHub: [GitHub Project](https://github.com/nebez/floppybird)

My problem is with the sound. If i play it in my web browser i do hear the sounds. If i upload it on PhoneGap, it doesn't.

I tried some things to fix this:

1. I changed the format of the sounds from `.ogg` to `.mp3`
2. I uploaded in my config.xml the following plugin: `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />`

3. i deleted all my files and re-build the app but nothing

I don't know what to do further.. I would definetly appreciate some help.
Thank you!

Comment: What device and OS are you testing on? Have you double checked it is not muted? Any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: I'm testing on an iPhone 6s. Yes, i checked both muted & sound to be minimum. I uninstalled the app several times and still nothing. No erros in js console because as i said, in browser it works perfect. I think the problem is in my config.xml where (i think) i should declare a media library or something like that.